# How to get rid of Javascript Runtime Errors when running PDT + XDebug in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, drupal, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am currently developing a Drupal webpage using PDT. When running without XDebug, the site works fine.

When I enable XDebug, the site works fine but opens up tons of Javascript errors that I need to click through.

Example:

A Runtime Error has occurred.
Do you wish to Debug?

Line: 1
Error: Syntax error

--

It seems to only be a problem when XDebug/PDT uses Firefox as its browser, this problem does not occur when using IE. Could it be some incompatability with Firebug?

Comment: If you are using Drupal4Firebug, you may find that the module works only on very specific configurations, and crashes on many pages.

Answer (score 2):

here is how to solve this problem:

Turn off XDebug output capture:

Window -> Preferences, expand PHP, expand Debug, select "Installed Debuggers", choose "XDebug", click "Configure" on the right to bring up the configure dialog. In the middle "Output Capture Settings", set "Capture stdout" to "Off".

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but try 
   Windows => Preferences => JavaScript => Include Path

Comment: Good thought, but no dice. It turns out it wasn't a path issue (I think).